# IIS-10 reverse proxy for BI internal server is not working

Tags: reverse-proxy, iis-10

I am followin this tutorial but I think I am missing something

https://www.tevpro.com/blog/using-iis-as-a-reverse-proxy-server

I am trying to send request like

https://192.168.1.77/bi/Dashboards/Pretrial%20PSA%20Dashboard?rs:embed=true

this will send request like below link which works when we directly send request.
https://192.168.1.77:9998/reports/powerbi/Dashboards/Pretrial%20PSA%20Dashboard?rs:embed=true

```
<rewrite>
        <rule name="IB Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="/bi/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https://192.168.1.77:9998/reports/powerbi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Hi I am trying to set reverse proxy on test server but I think I am missing something as I am getting 404 error when I try to hit BI server.

Comment: Enable FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules and then read the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the rewrite rule below:

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="IB Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="bi/(.*)" />
         <action type="Rewrite" url="https://192.168.1.77:9998/reports/powerbi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

changes:

`<match url="/bi/(.*)" />` to `<match url="bi/(.*)" />`

- For example, assuming that the URL address of the current website is
  https://test.com/Home/Index?page=1, then the part that matches the
  rule pattern is Home/Index.

`appendQueryString="false"` to `appendQueryString="true"`

- When set to true, the query string from the original URL will be
  appended to the replaced URL.

In addition, you need to enable ARR on the IIS server.

[image: image1]